# Double Riley of Melancholy

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix is served
>   Eat if you may
>   The prefix of my prefix
>   is a prefix, per se
>
> My infix is inside you
>   Within, it resides
>   The infix of my infix
>   can be seen from outside
>
> My suffix is a number
>   Count to address
>   The suffix of my suffix
>   is a suffix, just guess!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer could be:

> **Dishearten**.

```
My prefix is served
Eat if you may
The prefix of my prefix
is a prefix, per se
```

> This could be **Dish**, and the prefix of dish would be 'dis', which is also a common prefix.

```
My infix is inside you
Within, it resides
The infix of my infix
can be seen from outside
```

> This could be **Heart**, the organ, with the infix 'ear', which is an external organ, hence seen from outside.

```
My suffix is a number
Count to address
The suffix of my suffix
is a suffix, just guess!
```

> This could be **Ten**, as in the number 10, which has suffix 'en', another common suffix.

This further reinforces the title, as the answer is melancholic or dismal mood.